# How can I create Leverage Browser Caching using an .htaccess file?

Tags: html, .htaccess, caching

I recently submitted my first website to google, and I have a server error of 500 which I'm not sure what that means.

I'm guessing it has to do with the page speed of my site because I got 69/100, and it referred me to the following message:

Leverage browser caching
Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.
Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
golden_gate_bridge.jpg (expiration not specified)

I've tried to create a .htaccess file, and then put it in the root of my website, but every time I re-test my website for completion of Leveraging Browser Caching, google doesn't recognize any changes.

I'm guessing there is a meta tag part I'm missing, but I'm really lost trying to get this to work.

This is what I have so far:

.htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
```

I've read multiple articles telling me to put this in the root directory of my website server, but I'm not sure if I need a meta tag in each of my html files to connect it.  Please let me know what I'm missing, and thank you for your help.

Comment: First things first. A 500 wrote means something was completely broken when Google visited the page. Find  and fix that before you start thinking about page speed.

Comment: Error details
 
Last crawled: 4/24/16
First detected: 4/24/16
Googlebot couldn't access the contents of this URL because the server had an internal error when trying to process the request. These errors tend to be with the server itself, not with the request. More info.
When I clicked learn more, it said Error 500.  
I'm not sure what I did wrong though.

Comment: Blocked Resources
Rendering without certain resources can impair the indexing of your web pages. Learn more.
Google has not yet processed your site. Be sure to check all site variants.